# Six-step (trapezoidal) BLDC motor driving strategy

Tags: pwm, inverter, brushless-dc-motor, full-bridge

[image: typical BLDC driver output stage]

It seems that a common driving strategy for such a motor is to use the 3 half-bridge topology depicted above, and use PWM to regulate speed and/or torque.

At any given moment, two phases ("wires") of the motor are driven with PWM (or complementary PWM), and the third wire is left floating. For example, in a precise moment, mosfets 1 and 2 do complementary PWM, mosfet 4 is closed to GND (N), and all the other (3-4-5) are open (non conducting). The third wire can be, and sometimes is, used to read BEMF (velocity feedback).

What I would to know is: what happens if the third wire, normally left floating, gets tied to GND, or Udd, or modulated with a PWM?

I made some tries, but the results are unclear. My supposition was that the efficiency of the driving would decrease, because connecting the third wire to GND would consume energy shorting the BEMF to ground, and connecting the third wire to Udd would instead drive one more coil, perhaps contrasting the other two (driven) coils, or perhaps helping them...

What I have observed, and found interesting, is this: in "normal driving" (leaving the third wire open), when the speed of the motor is greater than the command (PWM) given to  it, i.e. when imposing deceleration, the power supply voltage Udd tends to rise (regenerative breaking). But in the same situation, if the third phase is connected to Udd, the rise is much more limited. This can be useful, and can be used to brake the motor without having a rise in power supply, but more gently than simply shorting its terminals.

Somebody knows what is happening? Is it possible to use the third wire, normally left floating, to achieve interesting results?

Comment: Oh yes that's possible and I'm doing it everyday. Look at this microchip app note for instance http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01299a.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjNraP4lNHqAhUqxYUKHSnzBoEQFjACegQIBxAO&usg=AOvVaw1LNUM7GmCEJhpqcQjqDc0p. More generally FOC algorithm commutes the 3 half bridges but need a position feedback (hall sensors or encoder), or use sensorless techniques to estimate rotor position (never used yet).

Comment: Interesting paper from Digikey: https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/controlling-sensorless-bldc-motors-via-back-emf

Comment: @MathieuG.: TY for the link, but it doesn't work - it leads to Microchip home page.

Comment: Sorry for the broken link. I was talking about AN1299. https://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en545803